# Splitting landcover polygons (parcels) into equal sizes, while retaining road access for all?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, editing, topology, parcel

I would like to split landcover polygons which surround a road polygon into equal sizes, while ALL resulting polygons should have access to the road!

Is there any chance to do this automatically? All programs, licenses etc. are welcome. I just don't have ANY idea how to solve this problem.

To make it more clear, I have attached a basic sketch.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload sketch to an image sharing site?

Comment: Konrad you need a rep of +10 to post images on GIS SE. So someone else needs to up vote your question.

Comment: Maybe he can post then link to the image and we can add it?

Comment: it seems difficult right !? :-/

Answer (score 5):

If you have an ArcEditor or ArcInfo license, you can use ArcGIS' [Parcel Fabric tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003wp000000.htm).

> In the parcel fabric, parcels can be divided by area to create new
>   parcels. Using the parcel division tool, you can divide parcels using
>   the following area-based division methods:
>
> - In equal widths
> - By proportional area
> - Into equal areas

[image]

I assume you want something like the image below?

[image]

Comment: Thanks R.K. for the reference to parcel division. I am aware of this function and tried it (altough its very complicated, I downloaded the 60 days trial version of ArcGIS advanced). The main problem is, that one can only specify the direction of division, but not further parameters such as the road access. Something like "all resulting polygons from division of Polygon A adjacent to Polygon B" Thanks for the additional Reps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this script would work for you: https://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2017/09/10/dividing-a-polygon-into-a-given-number-of-equal-areas-with-arcpy/

The script asks for your polygon and how many sections you want it to divide into. Then you tell it either to make cuts N-S or W-E (unfortunately, you won’t be able to specify the angle yourself) and it will divide the polygon up that way.

[image: The illustration of the polygon subdivision (West-East to the left, North-South to the right).]

The script write broke it down this way:

1.Get an extent of a polygon.
2. Construct a polyline using the vertices of the polygon’s extent with
    a tiny shift of coordinates.
3. Cut the polygon into two halves using this line.
4.Find what is the area of the smallest polygon.
5.If the area is smaller than the 200 sq. m. (that is, fifth part of
    the polygon), the shift the line again and re-run steps 2-4. 
6. If the area is 200 sq. m. or larger, than leave this part and keep
    working with the polygon that is left essentially running through
    the steps 2-5.
7. When the original polygon has been successfully divided into equal
    areas, they are inserted into a new feature class along with the
    source polygon attributes.

Comment: At the moment this is a link only answer and liable for deletion.  Please provide some information to describe the link contents, and why you think it should work